# How can I change the UI language of Qt Creator 1.3.1?

Tags: qt-creator

I just downloaded and installed Qt Creator 1.3.1 on my English Windows 7 system from the english download site at http://qt.nokia.com/downloads Apparently, however, the UI of Qt Creator is in German language, although the help files are in English.

From the FAQ at http://www.qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/pages/FrequentlyAskedQuestions I found the answer

*Qt Creator uses the language setting of the system it runs on. On Linux systems you can also override that language by setting the LANG  environment variable prior to starting Qt Creator, e.g. on the command line LANG=de ./qtcreator will run Qt Creator with german interface.*

This, however, is apparently not correct, as I have an English Windows, and as system locale I  have "English (United Kingdom)" set. Possibly Qt Creator interprets mistakenly the Windows settings for "current location", which I have set to "Germany" to mean that German would also be my language. However, changing that value had apparently no effect (maybe it should have been done before installing Qt Creator).

Is there any way to change the UI language of Qt creator to English after installing it, preferably without adjusting global system settings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I managed to modify the language setting without reinstalling by adding an environment variable LANG with the value en_US (right click on "Computer", "Properties", "Advanced system settings", "Environment variables" on Windows 7).

Comment: Or just run as `LANG=en_US designer` from bash (applies to Windows too)

Comment: It is wrong, why just for a UI language of an application change the whole system language?? The correct answer is the mLar answer. But I don't know why your answer voted up and accepted?? Amazing...

Answer (score 24):

on qt Creator, go to tools->options->environnement>general

Answer (score 8):

qt creator 5.3.1
Tools->Options->Environment->General->Language
and select language what you want.

Answer (score 6):

As mLar said but in German: go to Extras -> Einstellungen -> Umgebung -> Allgemein -> Sprache.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer from [qtforum.org](http://www.qtforum.org/post/94936/qt-designer-language-solved.html#post94936). Go to `[Qt_dir]\translations` and rename appropriate `designer_*.qm` file, so that designer wouldn't be able to locate it.

Comment: This has been the most useful for me (I don't use Qt Creator but VS with the add-in, so Creator-based solutions don't suit me)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the variable LANG with the setting en_US to solve this problem in Windows 7 and Vista.